# Correct way to disable snapd in Ubuntu Server 22.04?

Tags: server, mount

I'm very new to Ubuntu. I have several Raspberry Pi's to be used for a Kubernetes cluster with Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS (64-pit), installed using their Imager tool and running on SSD:

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

My goal is to optimize the OS for performance and remove any dependencies that will not be needed in a Kubernetes cluster environment.

Steps I performed so far:

1. Disable `atime` for directories and files:

```
# cat /etc/fstab
LABEL=writable  /   ext4    discard,noatime,errors=remount-ro   0 1
LABEL=system-boot       /boot/firmware  vfat    defaults        0 1
```

2. Disable `cloud-init` (made the boot time from 3 minutes to 20 seconds):

```
# touch /etc/cloud/cloud-init.disabled
```

3. Lastly, I want to disable `snapd`:

```
# snap list
Name    Version        Rev    Tracking       Publisher   Notes
core20  20230622       1977   latest/stable  canonical✓  base
lxd     5.0.2-838e1b2  24326  5.0/stable/…   canonical✓  -
snapd   2.60.4         20298  latest/stable  canonical✓  snap
```

I tried disabling each snap and rebooted the server, but the mounts are still present:

```
# for i in core20 lxd snapd; do snap disable $i; done
# for j in snapd.service snapd.seeded.service snapd.socket; do systemctl disable $j; done
# reboot
# df -ah | grep loop
/dev/loop0       60M   60M     0 100% /snap/core20/1977
/dev/loop1      110M  110M     0 100% /snap/lxd/24326
/dev/loop2       47M   47M     0 100% /snap/snapd/19459
/dev/loop3       36M   36M     0 100% /snap/snapd/20298
```

I temporarily started the snapd service to see if the snaps are properly disabled:

```
# for i in snapd.socket snapd.service snapd.seeded.service; do systemctl start $i; done
# snap list --all
Name    Version        Rev    Tracking       Publisher   Notes
core20  20230622       1977   latest/stable  canonical✓  base,disabled
lxd     5.0.2-838e1b2  24326  5.0/stable/…   canonical✓  disabled
snapd   2.59.5         19459  latest/stable  canonical✓  snapd,disabled
snapd   2.60.4         20298  latest/stable  canonical✓  snapd,disabled
```

Can you please let me know why the mounts are not removed?

I don't see any processes using the mounts, what's the correct way to remove these mounts?

```
# lsof | grep loop
```

Is it recommended to completely uninstall the snaps from OS, in my case?

Comment: Not a direct solution for you, but: Frankly, at this point, to go snap-less is probably easiest by using Debian.

Comment: Yes, I specifically need Ubuntu Server because the required OS libraries to run Cilium in Kubernetes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, the mounts are linked to installed snap packages, removing them will also remove the mounts, after a reboot. Since I'm automating the Kubernetes cluster deployment with Ansible, here are the relevant tasks mentioned into OP:

```
- name: Ubuntu Configuration
  notify: Reboot
  block:
    - name: Disable access time updates
      ansible.builtin.replace:
        path: /etc/fstab
        regexp: 'discard,errors'
        replace: 'discard,noatime,errors'

    - name: Disable cloud-init service
      ansible.builtin.file:
        path: /etc/cloud/cloud-init.disabled
        access_time: preserve
        modification_time: preserve
        state: touch
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode: '0644'

    - name: Set service facts
      ansible.builtin.service_facts:

    - name: Remove Snap Packages
      when:
        - ansible_facts.services['snapd.service'] is defined
        - ansible_facts.services['snapd.service'].state == 'running'
      block:
        - name: Get snap packages
          ansible.builtin.command:
            cmd: snap list
          changed_when: false
          register: snap_packages

        - name: Remove snap packages
          community.general.snap:
            name: '{{ item | split | first }}'
            state: absent
          loop: '{{ snap_packages.stdout_lines[1:] }}'
          when: snap_packages.stdout_lines[1:] is iterable

    - name: Disable snapd services
      ansible.builtin.systemd_service:
        name: '{{ item }}'
        state: stopped
        enabled: false
      loop:
        - snapd.service
        - snapd.seeded.service
        - snapd.socket
```

The optimizations posted above allowed me to reduce the boot time from over 3 minutes, to less than 10 seconds:

```
# systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 6.679s (kernel) + 3.239s (userspace) = 9.918s
graphical.target reached after 3.196s in userspace
```

Yes, I could go down the rabbit hole and further delete the snapd files and directories or even block further snap package installations. However, my goal was to implement only minimal changes to OS design, in order to avoid possible issues arising upon an upgrade.

It is also interesting to note that `snapd` is a dependency which will break `apparmor`, if uninstalled. Therefore, I've chosen only to disable the related services.

```
# apt rdepends --installed snapd
snapd
Reverse Depends:
  Recommends: ubuntu-server-raspi
  Recommends: ubuntu-server
  Breaks: apparmor (<< 2.44.3+20.04~)
  Recommends: ubuntu-server-raspi
  Recommends: ubuntu-server
  Breaks: apparmor (<< 2.44.3+20.04~)
  Suggests: command-not-found
```

Comment: I would rather remove snapd completely. It goes against the very core of open source, and opens an unverifiable backdoor. If dependency is forced, I would work towards removing the dependency. If that was not possible I would change the OS.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo systemctl stop snapd
```

```
sudo systemctl mask snapd
```